# FileNotFoundError in Heroku at deploying (Django)

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, collectstatic

When I run **python manage.py collectstatic --noinput** in my local machine, it works fine. But when heroku runs **python manage.py collectstatic --noinput** it gives error like this: ***for entry in os.scandir(path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_5d05d870/static'***

My project directory seems like this:

```
mysite-----|libooki(app)----------|migrations
           |----------------------|init.py
           |----------------------|admin.py
           |----------------------|........
-----------|media
-----------|media_cdn
-----------|mysite
-----------|static|--------------|css|------style.css
-----------|staticfiles
-----------|templates
-----------|.........
```

My **settings.py** seems like this. (I followed this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import django_heroku



BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ........,
    'libooki',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...........................................,
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media_cdn')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: I answered a very similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65898805/django-app-getting-server-error-500-on-local-host-when-debug-false/65924431 I hope this can help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django app getting server error 500 on local host when Debug = False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65898805/django-app-getting-server-error-500-on-local-host-when-debug-false)